# node_modules error: missing module postcss, when is present in node_modules/.bin

Tags: javascript, node-modules

I'm trying to run a package.json script (with yarn) however it seems to fail due to a missing module. However when checking node modules it seems the relevant module is there, so I'm not clear how to resolve the error.

```
~/P/j/tw-tutorial ❯❯❯ yarn build:css
yarn run v1.22.4
$ postcss src/css/tailwind.css -o src/css/main.css
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../'
Require stack:
- /Users/yunti/Projects/js/tw-tutorial/node_modules/.bin/postcss
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:835:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1012:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yunti/Projects/js/tw-tutorial/node_modules/.bin/postcss:3:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1123:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:872:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/yunti/Projects/js/tw-tutorial/node_modules/.bin/postcss' ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
~/P/j/tw-tutorial ❯❯❯ postcss src/css/tailwind.css -o src/css/main.css
fish: Unknown command: postcss
~/P/j/tw-tutorial ❯❯❯ npx postcss src/css/tailwind.css -o src/css/main.css
Cannot find module '../'
Require stack:
- /Users/yunti/Projects/js/tw-tutorial/node_modules/.bin/postcss
~/P/j/tw-tutorial ❯❯❯ ll ./node_modules/.bin | grep postcss
-rwxr-xr-x  1 yunti  staff    36B 24 Apr 10:20 postcss
```

update looks like the error is coming from postcss (not because postcss can't be found) as 
postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins:[
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss')({
            content: [
                '.src/**/*.js',
                '.src/**/*.jsx',
                './public/index.html',
            ],
            defaultExtractor: content=> content.match(/[A-Za-z0-9-_:/]+/g) || []
        })
],
};
```

Comment: postcss triggers the error. Presumably it references the module that is not found - which is `../`, so some string template instantiation may fail in the argument of a `require` call issued by `postcss`. Can you check the source code of that module? (Given the path you can as you seem to be the author ... silly me ;))

Comment: Thanks I updated with my postcss config file, I think it might be failing at the first `require('tailwindcss')` not sure why yet though.... as that's installed ok

Comment: and then it just started working.... not sure why.... brittle..